# How to connect ESP8266-01 (AT-commands) to its web server using AJAX

Tags: esp8266, web-server

I am just new on using AJAX in web server, I got an error on declaring "server" I am confused about this because I just used only a AT commands to used the ESP8266-01 (wifi-module) I hope you can help me, I want to get the data (distance) to print in the web server(page) in real-time(no refresh). So I used the AJAX for it but this code is still error. Advance thanks on anyhelp :)

```
 #include "NewPing.h"
 #include <SoftwareSerial.h>
 #define DEBUG true

 SoftwareSerial esp8266(10,11);
 #define TRIGGER_PIN 4
 #define ECHO_PIN 3
 #define MAX_DISTANCE 400

 NewPing sonar(TRIGGER_PIN,ECHO_PIN,MAX_DISTANCE);

 void setup() {
 Serial.begin (9600);
 Serial.println("START");
 esp8266.begin(9600);

 server.on("/",WebsiteContent);
 server.on("/xml",XMLcontent);
 server.begin();

 pinMode(TRIGGER_PIN, OUTPUT);
 pinMode(ECHO_PIN, INPUT);

 sendData("AT+RST\r\n",2000,DEBUG);
 sendData("AT+CWMODE=2\r\n",1000,DEBUG);
 sendData("AT+CIFSR\r\n",1000,DEBUG);
 sendData("AT+CIPMUX=1\r\n",1000,DEBUG);       
 sendData("AT+CIPSERVER=1,80\r\n",1000,DEBUG);


}

void javascriptContent(){
Javascript ="<SCRIPT>\n";
Javascript+="var xmlHttp=createXmlHttpObject();\n";
Javascript+="function createXmlHttpObject(){\n";
Javascript+="if(window.XMLHttpRequest){\n";
Javascript+="xmlHttp=new XMLHttpRequest();\n";
Javascript+="}else{\n";
Javascript+="xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');\n";
Javascript+="}\n";
Javascript+="return xmlHttp;\n";
Javascript+="}\n";
Javascript+="\n";
Javascript+="function response(){\n";
Javascript+="xmlResponse=xmlHttp.responseXML;\n";
Javascript+="xmldoc = xmlResponse.getElementsByTagName('data');\n";
Javascript+="message = xmldoc[0].firstChild.nodeValue;\n";
Javascript+="document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML=message;\n";
Javascript+="}\n";

Javascript+="function process(){\n";
Javascript+="xmlHttp.open('PUT','xml',true);\n";
Javascript+="xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=response;\n";
Javascript+="xmlHttp.send(null);\n";
Javascript+="setTimeout('process()',200);\n";
Javascript+="}\n";

Javascript+="</SCRIPT>\n";


}
void WebsiteContent(){
javascriptContent();

 Website="<html>\n";
 Website+="<style>\n";
 Website+="#div1{\n";
 Website+="width:400px;\n";
 Website+="margin:0 auto;\n";
 Website+="margin-top:130px;\n";
 Website+="font-size:900%;\n";
 Website+="color:powderblue;\n";
 Website+="}\n";
 Website+="</style>\n";
 Website+="<body onload='process()'>";
 Website+="<div id='div1'>"+data+"</div></body></html>";
 Website+=Javascript;
 server.send(200,"text/html",Website);
 }
 void XMLcontent(){

 XML ="<?xml version='1.0'?>";
 XML+="<data>";
 XML+=data;
 XML+="</data>";

 server.send(200,"text/xml",XML);

 }
 void loop()
 {

 delay(2000);  
 digitalWrite(TRIGGER_PIN, LOW);
 delayMicroseconds(2);
 digitalWrite(TRIGGER_PIN, HIGH);
 delayMicroseconds(10);
 digitalWrite(TRIGGER_PIN, LOW);

 long duration,distance;
 duration= pulseIn(ECHO_PIN,HIGH);

 distance = duration/58.2;

 data=(String)distance;
 delay(500); 

 server.handleClient();


 if(esp8266.available()) 
 {    
 if(esp8266.find("+IPD,"))
 {
 delay(1000);
 int connectionId = esp8266.read()-48;


 String cipSend = "AT+CIPSEND=";
 cipSend += connectionId;
 cipSend += ",";
 cipSend +=webpage.length();
 cipSend +="\r\n";
 sendData(cipSend,1000,DEBUG);
 sendData(webpage,1000,DEBUG);    
 String closeCommand = "AT+CIPCLOSE="; 
 closeCommand+=connectionId; 
 closeCommand+="\r\n";
 sendData(closeCommand,3000,DEBUG);

}
}
}
String sendData(String command, const int timeout, boolean debug)
{
String response = "";   
esp8266.print(command); 
long int time = millis();
while( (time+timeout) > millis())
{
  while(esp8266.available())
  {
    char c = esp8266.read(); 
    response+=c;
  }  
}
if(debug)
{
  Serial.print(command);
  Serial.print("> ");
  Serial.print(response);
}
return response;
}
```

Comment: Do you actually have a question? And is it related to Arduino, and not Javascript or HTML?

Comment: I already edited it sir :) sir do you have any idea about it?

Comment: Looks like you're confusing ESP8266 native code for Arduino code.

Comment: try to add a include `ESP8266WebServer server(80);`

Comment: @abu-ahmedal-khatiri I also add that earlier but still error

Comment: i cannot see on your code. you need to make a `index.h` to store data on AJAX [see my header](http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/48NvckZPQg/) and include it to your sketch [see my sketch](http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/6SGvsDF29T/)

Comment: @Majenko I used AT commands because when I program ESP8266 (directly) it's not working and always got error about it, so I switch on AT commands.

Comment: like a mentioned @Majenko answered "To use these kind of constructs you have to program the ESP8266, not the Arduino, and then you don't have the AT commands available." ,why you need AT Commands if you can store data to AJAX script directly?

Comment: ah so your example @abu-ahmedal-khatiri will work sir?

Comment: @abu-ahmedal-khatiri can you help me here sir? https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85432/discussion-on-question-by-xiaomy-arduino-uno-with-esp8266-01-with-at

Comment: anyone can help me about this ESP8266WebServer server(80); is error because I am using AT commands? because once I delete it the "server" methods are error too. Is there any alternatives here?

Comment: as mentioned in your question "I want to get the data (distance) to print in the web server(page) in real-time(no refresh)". I THINK you will display data to Web Page and MY ajaxcreated.h will works!. if you're using APP INVENTOR, the AJAX will not work!

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to mix code that is intended to run directly on an ESP8266 using ESP8266-specific libraries on an Arduino.  It can't ever work.

Likes like:

```
server.on("/",WebsiteContent);
server.on("/xml",XMLcontent);
server.begin();
```

are for use with the ESP8266's ESP8266WebServer library which doesn't run on an Arduino. To use these kind of constructs you have to program the ESP8266, not the Arduino, and then you don't have the AT commands available.

So, either:

- Do it *all* with AT commands only, or
- Ditch the Arduino and program the ESP8266 directly instead.

Comment: can you send me a link about that in AT commands?

Comment: You already use them in your code.

Comment: I thought there will be for AJAX or what

Comment: can you help me sir?

Comment: Do you know what the AT commands that you have in your sketch actually do?

Comment: it is for me to use it as alternative for coding esp8266 directly

Comment: Yes, but do you know what they **do**? What do they **mean**?

Comment: Delete all the `server` and such rubbish that you randomly added, and then work out how you can use what the ESP8266 sends you when you request a web page to decide what you should be sending and when you should be sending it.